# django pipeline Error: The file build/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' could not be found with <pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage object

Tags: django-pipeline

I am using django-pipeline, On running "sudo python manage.py collectstatic"

Getting this error:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) 
File "/Users/office/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() 
File "/Users/office/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) 
File "/Users/office/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **cmd_options) 
File "/Users/office/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute output = self.handle(*args, **options) 
File "/Users/office/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 168, in handle collected = self.collect() 
File "/Users/office/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 120, in collect raise processed ValueError: The file 'bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' could not be found with <pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage object at 0x10d274e10>.
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using django-pipeline-forgiving(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pipeline-forgiving) solved the issue.

- pip install django-pipeline-forgiving
- Set in your settings.py: STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django_pipeline_forgiving.storages.PipelineForgivingStorage'

Comment: Sounds like you're not fixing the underlying issue but just muting the error.